# PDO Working With BLOBs (get image from table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a little problem with getting an image from database table, maybe someone could help me.
I have an database named:

```
 -RESPONSES with next rows->
id,
user_avatar,
first_name,
last_name,
msg_user,
user_date,
```

AND PHP insertion into DataBase:

```
if (isset($_POST['r_sub'])) {
    $image = $_FILES['r_image'];
    $user_name = $_POST['r_username'];
    $last_u_name = $_POST['r_lastname'];
    $user_msg = $_POST['r_usermsg'];
    $u_date = $_POST['r_date'];

    $q_r = "INSERT INTO responses (user_avatar, first_name, last_name, msg_user, user_date) VALUES (:image, :user_name, :last_u_name, :user_msg, :u_date);";
    $query_r = $pdo->prepare($q_r);
    $results = $query_r->execute(array(
        ":image" => $image,
        ":user_name" => $user_name,
        ":last_u_name" => $last_u_name,
        ":user_msg" => $user_msg,
        ":u_date" => $u_date));
    header("Location: index.php");
```

I'm wondering how to get a BLOB from table (in my case : `user_avatar`);
maybe somebody has an a ready-made solution for this problem? I'm really need an example of code!

Comment: So your question is how to perform a `SELECT` query using PDO?

Comment: That's right! SELECT image from table user_avatar!

Comment: @ЮрійМориляк In this case why did you provide INSERT code? Do you want to select binary data and output it as an image?

Comment: Probably i dont have no idea how to work with BLOB, it seems to me i have to store a binary code of an image, and select a binary code. User4035 - you are right!

Comment: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_avatar FROM responses WHERE id = :id")`. Bind the `:id` or any other parameters that you need and that's it, you can fetch the data. I might be a bit unclear on what confuses you, whether it's SQL syntax or something else. You work with a BLOB like with any other column in PHP.

Comment: Thanks N.B i'll try it out!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image->load()) .'" />';
```

make sure that

```
$image->load()
```

is your selected image from database